# Where does prop argument come from in React?

Tags: reactjs

In react you can declare a function or class component and use the prop object inside to make your code more reusable. However I can't seem to figure out where the prop argument itself comes from.

```
function Welcome(props) {
  return <h1>Hello, {props.name}</h1>;
}
```

or

```
 class Welcome extends React.Component {
render() {
 return <h1>Hello, {this.props.name}</h1>;
 }
}
```

and then you can create instances like so:

```
<Welcome name="Larry" />
<Welcome name="Tim" />
```

I can't seem to grasp where the props object comes from in either of the examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your confusion comes from the fact that you are looking at JSX (as opposed to plain javascript). This JSX gets compiled to plain Javascript and what gets executed is this:

```
React.createElement(Welcome, {name: 'Larry'}, null)
```

You can see in this example that `Welcome` is your component, and the object passed as second argument to `createElement` function is the `props`.

You can read more about this on the React website ([React without JSX](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-without-jsx.html))